# Program stuck while sorting 20million element with this quickSort

Tags: c, quicksort

i have to sort an array of a specific struct called Data. There are 3 field but for now i want to sort only for string field. The array is filled by reading from a file. So far no problem, if i read 8k row from the file the array is sorted correctly and the value can be printed. But the request is to sort a file with 20milion row. When i try to run with this file it seems to stuck but doesn't give segmentation fault neither compiling with address sanitaizer. **What would be the problem with this quickSort?**

**Why with a pivot in the first element it doesn't sort the array?Did i miss something in the algorithm?**

I just try to change the pivot in the function but if i take the first element or the middle too, it doesn't sort correctly.

```
typedef struct _data
{
    int id;
    char field1[50];
    int field2;
    float field3;
}Data;

typedef struct _GenericArray{
  void **array;
  int size;
  int capacity;
  int (*compare)(void*, void*);
}GenericArray;


void swap(Data* x,Data* y){
     if(x == NULL){
        printf("Can't swap a NULL element(x is NULL)!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(y == NULL){
        printf("Can't swap a NULL element(y is NULL)!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Data temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y=temp;
}

int partition(GenericArray* generic_array,int first,int last){
    
    if(generic_array == NULL){
        printf("Can't do quickSort in an empty array!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Data *pivot = generic_array->array[last];
    int i = first;
    
    for (int j = first; j < last ;j++)
    {
        if(generic_array->compare(generic_array->array[j],pivot)<=0){
            swap(generic_array->array[i],generic_array->array[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    swap(generic_array->array[i],generic_array->array[last]);

    return i;
}

int quick_sort(GenericArray* generic_array,int first,int last){
    
    if(generic_array == NULL){
        //printf("Can't do quickSort in an empty array!");
        return -1;
    }
   
    if(first<last){
        int p = partition(generic_array,first,last);
        quick_sort(generic_array,first,p-1);
        quick_sort(generic_array,p+1,last);
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare_string(void* item1, void* item2){  //function in generic_array->compare
    Data *a = (Data*)item1;
    Data *b = (Data*)item2;
    if(strcmp(a->field1,b->field1)==0) return 0;
    else if(strcmp(a->field1,b->field1)>0) return 1;
    else return -1; 
    
}
```

Comment: 20 million elements is very much larger than 8000. It will take a *much* longer time to sort. Increase the data-set size gradually to measure the time it takes, and plot it out and see if you can make a curve to extrapolate.

Comment: It is recursive. Every recursion consumes plenty of stack memory which is limited. Stack overflow does not have to give segfault as it is UB

Comment: Also, is your assignment to create the sorting implementation yourself? Or is there another reason you can't use the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)?

Comment: Is the input data maybe already sorted? If it is, then always selecting the first element as a pivot will give you the worst-case [time-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: And when data elements are large, it's usually a lot faster to sort *pointers* to the elements than it is to sort the elements themselves.  It's a lot faster to swap two pointers than it is to swap two much larger `struct` values.  You have to weigh that against the overhead of an additional array of pointers.

Comment: And why "read" **then** "sort"?  Something like inserting nodes into a b-tree as you read them in will enable trivial retrieval of sorted results.

Comment: Though you seem already to have chosen an array of pointers, so it's particularly strange that you are swapping the pointed-to struct values instead of just the pointers.

Comment: Note that `strcmp` already returns a signed value, there's no real need to execute it twice in the comparator function. Also, consider using the median of three values, instead of the last one as a pivot.

Comment: [hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) using middle value as pivot or median of 3 or median of 3 medians of 3 would be faster. This is a case where doing a merge sort on the array of pointers would be faster than quicksort. Merge sort does more moves, but fewer compares than quick sort, and in this case, pointers would be moved and strings compared.

Comment: The request is to implement the sorting algorithm by my self. I can't change the list cause it's a requirement. So i will try to swap only the pointers to the element and see if there will be any changes. The input data read from the file are not in order so the pivot with first element should work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger could you give me an example of how i should change the swap function?

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello, in your present swap function, change every appearance of `Data` to `Data *`.  You will also need to make corresponding changes in how you call it.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try it but there is always a problem. If i choose a different pivot than the last element the algorithm doesn't sort correctly, Why?

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello, with your original swap function, if you choose an element other than the last as the pivot then it is likely that the data pointed to by `pivot` will be swapped out from under it on some runs of the partition function. That would produce an incorrect sort. That particular issue would be fixed by changing the swap function as already discussed.